# how to Filter the full Log context using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, logging, powershell-5.0, select-string

I am trying to filter out the logs and its full context using Select-String in powershell. I know the parameters of context and their meanings but this limits to what I am trying to achieve. Below is the log snippet and I want to search the log with date as a search parameter to select-string filter.

```
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 16 Dec 2019 19:03:32,371 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics - will requeue for later transmission
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Connection back off limitation in effect: /controller/instance/417/metrics
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run(AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:335)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask.runAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:152)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:119)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.run(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:236)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:694)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:726)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[AD Thread Pool-Global0] 16 Dec 2019 19:03:37,956 ERROR SystemAgentPollingForUpdate - Fatal transport error while connecting to URL [/controller/instance/417/systemagentpolling]: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to imswt01.ecbt1.tadnet.net:8090 [imswt01.ecbt1.tadnet.net/10.228.18.71] failed: connect timed out
[AD Thread Pool-Global0] 16 Dec 2019 19:03:37,956  WARN SystemAgentPollingForUpdate - Invalid response for configuration request from controller/could not connect. Msg: Fatal transport error while connecting to URL [/controller/instance/417/systemagentpolling]
[AD Thread Pool-Global0] 16 Dec 2019 19:03:37,956  WARN SystemAgentPollingForUpdate - System configuration request failed 5 times consecutively.
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 16 Dec 2019 19:03:42,362 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics - will requeue for later transmission
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Connection back off limitation in effect: /controller/instance/417/metrics
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run(AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:335)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask.runAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:152)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:119)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.run(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:236)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:694)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:726)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I run my code

```
Select-String "16 Dec 2019" -context 0,10
```

Then it filters 10 lines below the match expression. My problem is, what if the context of the log entry is bigger with many lines? Is there anyway we keep searching and printing until the new log entry is recorded? like and we get the whole Log entry context without limiting the context?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

`Select-String` can be made to work but it would be cumbersome impov.
I'd use a switch statement instead implementing a simple state machine.

```
$inContext = $false
gc yourlog | % {
    switch -RegEx ($_) {
        "16 Dec 2019" {$inContext = $true; $_ ; continue} 
        "^\[" {$inContext = $false; continue}
        default {if ($inContext) {$_}}
    }
}
```

**Edit** <sub>cudo's to mklement0</sub>

```
$inContext = $false
switch -File yourlog -RegEx {
        "16 Dec 2019" {$inContext = $true; $_ ; continue} 
        "^\[" {$inContext = $false; continue}
        default {if ($inContext) {$_}}
}
```

**Edit2** <sub>poc using provided example</sub>

```
$inContext = $false
@'
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 16 Dec 2019 19:03:32,371 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics - will requeue for later transmission
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Connection back off limitation in effect: /controller/instance/417/metrics
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run(AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:335)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask.runAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:152)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:119)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.run(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:236)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:694)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:726)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[AD Thread Pool-Global0] 16 Dec 2019 19:03:37,956 ERROR SystemAgentPollingForUpdate - Fatal transport error while connecting to URL [/controller/instance/417/systemagentpolling]: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to imswt01.ecbt1.tadnet.net:8090 [imswt01.ecbt1.tadnet.net/10.228.18.71] failed: connect timed out
[AD Thread Pool-Global0] 16 Dec 2019 19:03:37,956  WARN SystemAgentPollingForUpdate - Invalid response for configuration request from controller/could not connect. Msg: Fatal transport error while connecting to URL [/controller/instance/417/systemagentpolling]
[AD Thread Pool-Global0] 16 Dec 2019 19:03:37,956  WARN SystemAgentPollingForUpdate - System configuration request failed 5 times consecutively.
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 16 Dec 2019 19:03:42,362 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics - will requeue for later transmission
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Connection back off limitation in effect: /controller/instance/417/metrics
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run(AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:335)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask.runAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:152)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:119)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.run(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:236)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:694)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:726)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 16 Dec 2019 19:03:52,369 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics - will requeue for later transmission
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Connection back off limitation in effect: /controller/instance/417/metrics
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run(AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:335)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask.runAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:152)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:119)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.run(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:236)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:694)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:726)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[extension-scheduler-pool-1] 16 Dec 2019 19:03:55,283  WARN ProcessMonitor - ProcessMonitor::Caught exception during collection and reporting.
feign.RetryableException: Connect to imswt01.ecbt1.tadnet.net:8090 [imswt01.ecbt1.tadnet.net/10.228.18.71] failed: Connection refused: connect executing PUT http://imswt01.ecbt1.tadnet.net:8090/controller/sim/v2/agent/machines/imswd97/processes
    at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:67)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:102)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.updateProcessMetadata(Unknown Source)
    at com.appdynamics.sim.agent.extensions.servers.DoubleBufferedProcessProperties.reportProcesses(DoubleBufferedProcessProperties.java:75)
    at com.appdynamics.sim.agent.extensions.servers.ProcessMonitor.run(ProcessMonitor.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to imswt01.ecbt1.tadnet.net:8090 [imswt01.ecbt1.tadnet.net/10.228.18.71] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:165)
    at com.appdynamics.voltron.rest.client.impl.apache.ManagedHttpClient.execute(ManagedHttpClient.java:83)
    at com.appdynamics.voltron.rest.client.impl.apache.ApacheClientImpl.execute(ApacheClientImpl.java:77)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:97)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 25 more
[system-thread-0] 16 Dec 2019 19:03:55,643  WARN RegistrationTask - Encountered error during registration. Will retry in 60 seconds.
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter0] 16 Dec 2019 19:04:00,003  WARN ManagedMonitorDelegate - Metric Reporter Queue full. Dropping metrics.
[system-thread-0] 16 Dec 2019 19:04:02,013  WARN DynamicMonitoringModeTask - Encountered error checking monitoring mode. Will retry in 60 seconds.
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 16 Dec 2019 19:04:02,357 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics - will requeue for later transmission
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Connection back off limitation in effect: /controller/instance/417/metrics
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run(AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:335)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask.runAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:152)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:119)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.run(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:236)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:694)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:726)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[system-thread-0] 16 Dec 2019 19:04:08,387  WARN RegistrationTask - Encountered error during registration. Will retry in 60 seconds.
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 16 Dec 2019 19:04:12,358 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics - will requeue for later transmission
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Connection back off limitation in effect: /controller/instance/417/metrics
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run(AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:335)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask.runAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:152)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:119)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.run(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:236)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:694)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:726)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[Agent-Scheduler-1] 16 Dec 2019 19:04:23,615 ERROR ControllerTimeSkewHandler - Error response from controller: Connection back off limitation in effect: /controller/instance/417/current-time
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 16 Dec 2019 19:04:27,365 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Fatal transport error while connecting to URL [/controller/instance/417/metrics]: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to imswt01.ecbt1.tadnet.net:8090 [imswt01.ecbt1.tadnet.net/10.228.18.71] failed: connect timed out
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 16 Dec 2019 19:04:27,365  WARN ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metric data to controller:Fatal transport error while connecting to URL [/controller/instance/417/metrics]
[AD Thread-Metric Reporter1] 16 Dec 2019 19:04:27,365 ERROR ManagedMonitorDelegate - Error sending metrics - will requeue for later transmission
com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.metrics.MetricSendException: Fatal transport error while connecting to URL [/controller/instance/417/metrics]
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.AMetricSubscriber.publish(AMetricSubscriber.java:350)
    at com.singularity.ee.agent.commonservices.metricgeneration.MetricReporter.run(MetricReporter.java:113)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl$SafeRunnable.run(AgentScheduledExecutorServiceImpl.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:335)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADFutureTask.runAndReset(ADFutureTask.java:152)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:119)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ADScheduledFutureTask.run(ADScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:236)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:694)
    at com.singularity.ee.util.javaspecific.scheduler.ADThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ADThreadPoolExecutor.java:726)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  [system-thread-0] 16 Dec 2019 19:05:54,030  WARN DynamicMonitoringModeTask - Encountered error checking monitoring mode. Will retry in 60 seconds.
[system-thread-0] 16 Dec 2019 19:05:54,030  WARN RegistrationTask - Encountered error during registration. Will retry in 60 seconds.
[system-thread-0] 16 Dec 2019 19:05:54,030  WARN DynamicMonitoringModeTask - Encountered error checking monitoring mode. Will retry in 60 seconds.
[system-thread-0] 16 Dec 2019 19:05:54,030  WARN RegistrationTask - Encountered error during registration. Will retry in 60 seconds.
[system-thread-0] 16 Dec 2019 19:05:54,030  WARN DynamicMonitoringModeTask - Encountered error checking monitoring mode. Will retry in 60 seconds.
[system-thread-0] 16 Dec 2019 19:05:54,046  WARN RegistrationTask - Encountered error during registration. Will retry in 60 seconds.
[system-thread-0] 16 Dec 2019 19:05:54,046  WARN DynamicMonitoringModeTask - Encountered error checking monitoring mode. Will retry in 60 seconds.
[system-thread-0] 16 Dec 2019 19:05:54,046  WARN RegistrationTask - Encountered error during registration. Will retry in 60 seconds.
[system-thread-0] 16 Dec 2019 19:05:54,046  WARN DynamicMonitoringModeTask - Encountered error checking monitoring mode. Will retry in 60 seconds.
[system-thread-0] 16 Dec 2019 19:05:54,046  WARN RegistrationTask - Encountered error during registration. Will retry in 60 seconds.
[extension-scheduler-pool-6] 18 Dec 2019 19:31:36,365  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected and reported through the SIM extension because SIM is enabled.
[extension-scheduler-pool-3] 18 Dec 2019 19:36:36,369  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected and reported through the SIM extension because SIM is enabled.
[extension-scheduler-pool-9] 18 Dec 2019 19:41:36,374  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected and reported through the SIM extension because SIM is enabled.
[extension-scheduler-pool-11] 18 Dec 2019 19:46:36,378  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected and reported through the SIM extension because SIM is enabled.
[extension-scheduler-pool-1] 18 Dec 2019 19:51:36,382  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected and reported through the SIM extension because SIM is enabled.
[extension-scheduler-pool-7] 18 Dec 2019 19:56:36,387  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected and reported through the SIM extension because SIM is enabled.
[extension-scheduler-pool-8] 18 Dec 2019 20:01:36,391  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected and reported through the SIM extension because SIM is enabled.
[extension-scheduler-pool-7] 18 Dec 2019 20:06:36,396  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected and reported through the SIM extension because SIM is enabled.
[extension-scheduler-pool-9] 18 Dec 2019 20:11:36,400  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected and reported through the SIM extension because SIM is enabled.
[extension-scheduler-pool-6] 18 Dec 2019 20:16:36,405  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - Basic metrics will be collected and reported through the SIM extension because SIM is enabled.
[extension-scheduler-pool-4] 18 Dec 2019 20:21:36,409  INFO ReportMetricsConfigSupplier - 
'@ -split "`r`n" | % {
    switch -RegEx ($_) {
        "16 Dec 2019" { $inContext = $true; $_ ; continue} 
        "^\["{ $inContext = $false; continue}
        default { if ($inContext) {$_}}
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the response but your logic is printing out the whole log file rather than printing out the matched parameter "16 Dec 2019" and its contexts.

Comment: @MuntazirAbbas - can you post your logfile?

Comment: Even the above script is not producing the right output. just line with matched string @LievenKeersmaekers

Comment: @MuntazirAbbas - we can not see what you see. I assumed a context stopped on `[AD` but looking at what you've posted, that is incorrect. I have adjusted the stop condition to `^\[` *(a line beginning with [)*

Comment: thank you so much @LievenKeersmaekers i got it now. You saved my day man.

Comment: @MuntazirAbbas - my bad. Replace the `break` with `continue` and it should work.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers is it possible to put multiple expressions like 16 Dec 2019 and 17 Dec 2019 for example and extract the logs?

Comment: @MuntazirAbbas - yes, multiple ways to do so but the easiest would be to adjust the regex from `16 Dec 2019` to `1[67] Dec 2019`.

Comment: actually what we want is to keep logs for max 3 days old so i will use variables for these dates. thats why i want to check if multiple parameters can be passed ? like $currenrDate = Get-Date, $OneDayOld = $currenrDate.AddDays(-1), $TwoDayOld=$currenrDate.AddDays(-1)

Comment: @MuntazirAbbas - You should [accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to some of your past questions. Not only will this show your appreciation for the people who spent their own time to help you, but it will improve your accept rate and the chances that they will answer any future questions you may have.

Comment: As for your last question, all possible but it looks to me like you are solving this backwards. If you create logfiles on a per day basis, you don't need all this parsing.